# writing a glibc api for a system call

Tags: c, linux, unix, glibc, system-calls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need help with glibc source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515583/need-help-with-glibc-source)

I understand how to implement our own system calls in linux kernel. I know we can call this with `syscall()` or with `_asm()` in a c program.

1. But I want to understand how to write glibc api for this new system call?.
2. How the `open()` and `read()` glibc function calls mapping into system call in kernel?.

   ```
   char      message[ ] = "Hello!\n";

   int main( void )
   {
           write( 1, message, 7 );
           exit( 0 );
   }
   ```

When I convert the above program into assembly it is  giving

```
main:
    leal    4(%esp), %ecx
    andl    $-16, %esp
    pushl   -4(%ecx)
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    pushl   %ecx
    subl    $20, %esp
    movl    $7, 8(%esp)
    movl    $message, 4(%esp)
    movl    $1, (%esp)
    call    write
    movl    $0, (%esp)
    call    exit
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Debian 4.3.2-1.1) 4.3.2"
    .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

~

3, In "call write" I think write is glibc call here ?. what happens after that? how it maps the glibc call to system call?

Comment: Have you tried looking into glibc source code? There are plenty of examples.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548779/function-calls-from-fork-to-do-fork

Answer (score 2):

See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10151524/841108) and [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11609768/841108) to similar questions. Read also more about [syscalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall), the [linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel), an overview of [linux syscalls](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), and the [assembly howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/)

The `write` function from glibc is not the true syscall. It is a wrapper (doing the sycall thru e.g. `sysenter` machine instruction, perhaps with the [VDSO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDSO), and setting `errno`).
You can use `strace` to understand the system calls done by some program.

For example, the [MUSL libc](http://www.musl-libc.org/) has this [write.c](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/unistd/write.c) implementation for `write`. For GNU libc, look at its [write.c](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=io/write.c;hb=HEAD).

Comment: Basile, Thanks for the quick reply. I understand how it is working in kernel. I could not get glibc mapping to system call where it is generating interrupt . see in your example in  MUSL libc in write.c i see "return syscall_cp(SYS_write, fd, buf, count);" . I guess this is similar to syscall() in glibc. But, I am not finding in glibc write() definition where it is sending int $0x80.  Thanks Again

Comment: I guess that glibc is not doing directly an `int 80` it is using the VDSO, as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I think the glibc code isn't the correct implementation of `write()`; instead it's a stub that gets inserted when `write()` isn't available. But I couldn't find the correct implementation, either :-/ See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515583/need-help-with-glibc-source