# How is assembly IO performed for text based stuff?

Tags: linux, nasm, stdio, text-based

I'm looking to understand how to do basic input/output to write a text based game in x86 assembly, simply for the sake of learning of the instruction set and the internals.

I don't want to use `stdlib.h` or `stdio.h`in my assembly code unless it involves something complicated like `printf`, which I'd then call from assembly.

I'd like to learn how to emulate enums and structs if possible. AFAIK writing functions and sending them params is just a case of pushing/popping specific registers on and off the stack and/or manipulating `esp` using multiples of 4.

How would I do this in x86 using intel syntax?

**Update**

Sorry, I forgot to specify the target - I'm using Linux.

---

**Example Code - Function prototype implementation omitted for sake of brevity**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef enum __weapon_type__ {

    weapon_type_sword = 1, 
    weapon_type_spear = 2, 
    weapon_type_knife = 3

} weapon_type;

typedef struct __weapon__ {

    unsigned int damage;
    char*        name;
    weapon_type  type;  

} weapon;

weapon* weapon_create( int damage, char* name, weapon_type type );

void putline( const char* msg );

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    unsigned int weapon_selection, weapon_damage;
    weapon_type weptype;
    weapon* player_weapon = NULL;
    char* weapon_name = NULL;

    putline( "Choose your weapon type:\t" );
    putline( "(1) Sword" );
    putline( "(2) Spear" );
    putline( "(3) Knife" );

    while ( weapon_selection > 3 || weapon_selection < 1 )
    {
        scanf( "%u", &weapon_selection );

        switch( weapon_selection )
        {
            case 1:
                weptype = weapon_type_sword;
                break;
            case 2: 
                weptype = weapon_type_spear;
                break;
            case 3:
                weptype = weapon_type_knife;
                break;
            default:
                putline( "ERROR! Please select options 1 - 3\t" );
                break;
        }
    }

    /*do the same thing for weapon_damage and weapon_name, etc.
      Then ask for player name, type of character, blah blah blah.
    */

    player_weapon = weapon_create( weapon_damage, weapon_name, weptype );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: HAve you tried to compile C code to ASM and look at it?

Comment: I thought of that, the only problem is it wouldn't necessarily cover the IO aspects of the code (unless I'm wrong here) in terms of the implementation; i.e., wouldn't it just be making extern calls to the c library?

Comment: IO is platform dependent - ultimately code will need to call OS function to do so - will be different depending on Linux/DOS/Windows/other target. Basically it looks like you need to learn OS functions to output text and how to call OS functions from Asm - specifying exact target will let someone answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux applications, all I/O is done thru [syscalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall) (which from the application point of view, are elementary operations, usually implemented thru a mode-switching machine instruction like `SYSENTER`, `SYSCALL`, `INT` ...). I suggest reading the [linux assembly howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/).

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12563270/841108) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11609768/841108) answers.

Look at the output of the compiler, using `gcc -Wall -fverbose-asm -O -S your-c.c`. You'll learn that a call to `printf` or to any C function is (on x86 in 32 bits) pushing arguments on the stack (on x86-64 some arguments are passed in registers). There are some [calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions), e.g. those defined (for x86-64) in the [x86-64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) (a similar document exist for other architectures). A C `enum` is just a way to define some constants. A C `struct` is just an aggregate i.e. a memory zone with data inside etc.